# I am trying to use ggplot2, and I am getting an error when trying to edit x-axis of my histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am currently running through a slightly out of date R course on Udacity. Part of the course gets me to make a histogram using a dataset using ggplot, and try to modify the x-axis (to show days of the month).
The first step I make is running this code:

```
qplot(x = dob_day, data = pf)
`stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with
`binwidth`.
```

This creates the histogram with no issues (the stat bin error message is there intentionally I believe, as part of the course learning), however the x-axis is in multiples of 10. The course then says to run this code:

```
qplot(x = dob_day, data = pf)+
 scale_x_discrete(breaks=1:31)
```

but this shows the following error and does not create the histogram, whereas in the course it does with no error:

```
Error: StatBin requires a continuous x variable: the x variable is discrete.Perhaps you want stat="count"?
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

I have run rlang/last error and got this:

```
<error/rlang_error>
StatBin requires a continuous x variable: the x variable is discrete.Perhaps you want stat="count"?
```

I understand the code is telling me the data needs to be formatted as continuous to do this, but I have no idea how to resolve this (either reformat the data or rewrite my ggplot code to take this into account).
Here is the str() of the data set I am working with:

```
str(pf)
'data.frame':   99003 obs. of  16 variables:
 $ userid               : int  2094382 1192601 2083884 1203168 1733186 1524765 1136133 1680361 1365174 1712567 ...
 $ age                  : int  14 14 14 14 14 14 13 13 13 13 ...
 $ dob_day              : int  19 2 16 25 4 1 14 4 1 2 ...
 $ dob_year             : int  1999 1999 1999 1999 1999 1999 2000 2000 2000 2000 ...
 $ dob_month            : int  11 11 11 12 12 12 1 1 1 2 ...
 $ gender               : chr  "male" "female" "male" "female" ...
 $ tenure               : int  266 6 13 93 82 15 12 0 81 171 ...
 $ friend_count         : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ friendships_initiated: int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ likes                : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ likes_received       : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ mobile_likes         : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ mobile_likes_received: int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ www_likes            : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ www_likes_received   : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ dob_Day              : Factor w/ 31 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 19 2 16 25 4 1 14 4 1 2 ...
```

and here is the table() for the variable I am working with:

```
table(pf$dob_day)

   1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12 
7900 3409 3291 3217 3545 3108 3010 3202 3003 4030 3097 3413 
  13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24 
2881 3219 3555 2994 3266 3083 2967 3263 2816 2838 2864 2807 
  25   26   27   28   29   30   31 
3217 2753 2755 2955 2508 2530 1507
```

I would send the entire raw data, but the dataset is too large and completely over takes my console screen, going beyond the limits of my scrollbar.
Any input as to the issue and a solution is much appreciated.
Apologies for any simple mistakes, I am new to R and am still learning.

Comment: As per the error, try with `scale_x_continuous(breaks=1:31)`

Comment: Thanks Phil, that fixed the problem. Not quite sure how, but it works. :)

Answer (score 0):

Phil commented on my question with a fix:

```
scale_x_continuous(breaks=1:31)
```

Not quite sure the mechanism behind the fix, but I assume it is to do with changing the data type in the code, allowing it to function. Perhaps an issue caused by my training course being pre R4?